# Is the observable universe analogous to a white hole?

Tags: spacetime, universe, space-expansion, big-bang, white-holes

My instinct is no, but my lack of understanding with respects to white holes doesn't tell me why. My thinking is this: The universe is expanding and the further away from us the faster it is expanding. Therefore, there is an event horizon from which nothing can reach us that is the edge of the observable universe. Things from within this boundary can and will cross that horizon disappearing from our view forever, their velocity away exceeding the speed of light, however the inverse is not true. Objects (or radiation) will not slow down to cross into the observable region (I believe). To me, this would be analogous to an outside observer of a horizon emitting matter/radiation which sounds like a white hole. Or would an outside observer even see a horizon? I'll leave it at this for now, but I am also curious about implications of an AMPS firewall at the horizon to an outside observer.

Answer (score -2):

If u consider a dimension as a generalised reduction of field theories in a geometric way to conform to a gauge field in compactified dimension,and string like,then the quantum state of a energy field as a vector potential could be thought of as flowing symplectic form from a white hole like superluminal entity