# Is the Universe inside the event horizon of a white hole or a black hole or none?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, universe, white-holes

I have read this question:

[Is the observable universe analogous to a white hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/373244/is-the-observable-universe-analogous-to-a-white-hole)

But it does not have a satisfying answer.

And this one:

[Is the observable region of the universe within the event horizon of a super-massive black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26193/is-the-observable-region-of-the-universe-within-the-event-horizon-of-a-super-mas?rq=1)

[Are we inside a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23118/are-we-inside-a-black-hole?noredirect=1&lq=1)

This one says that we are not inside a black hole, because:

1. The large scale geometry of the universe is described by the Friedmann-Lemaitre-Robertson-Walker metric.
2. The geometry of the spacetime of a black hole (in its simplest form) is described by the Schwarzschild metric.

Now here:

[The largest black hole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/471636/the-largest-black-hole)

Safesphere's comment says that our universe is inside a white hole.

Question:

1. Which one is it, is our universe inside a black hole or a white hole or none?

Comment: According to the standard model of cosmology (Lambda-CDM), neither.

Comment: @G.Smith Actually, $\Lambda\text{CDM}$ is consistent with the universe being an Oppenheimer-Snyder white hole. Both are described by the same Friedmann metric and therefore cannot be distinguished by observations.